# How can I decrypt blowfish encrypted string without using OpenSSL in Mac OS 10.5/10.6

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, encryption, osx-snow-leopard

My application is currently using SSCrypto.framework to decrypt a string encrypted with Blowfish. SSCrypto utilizes OpenSSL which is a new problem for me. Using the 10.6 base SDK while targeting 10.5 doesn't seem to work. The issue is explained in this Apple Mailing List thread: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Cocoa-dev/2009/Aug/msg01737.html

I have to use Blowfish or all copies currently in the field would stop working once they were updated (they rely on a previously stored Blowfish encrypted string which they have to be able to decrypt and verify).

Comment: What do you mean by "using the 10.6 base SDK while targeting 10.5"? As this seems mutually exclusive, an example might help the answers.

Comment: Did you try both solutions suggested in the thread you linked to? Did they not work for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL has a very permissive license, so just link it into your app as a static library. You should then still be able to use the SSCrypto framework, or you can just call the OpenSSL libcrypto routines directly.

Step 1:  Build openssl from source: [Download OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8k.tar.gz)
Step 2:  Add a header search path to Xcode, pointing to the OpenSSL include directory for the source tree you built
Step 3:  Link against libcrypto.a.  Note:  to prevent XCode from linking against the system's dynamic copy of libcryto, do NOT add libcrypto.a to your XCode project.  If you do, that will add a -lcrypto to the linker command, and the linker will resolve that by looking for a dynamic library first (which it will find in /usr/lib - exactly what you don't want)
Instead, put the full path to the library in "Other Linker Flags"

Step 4:  Build.

Answer (score 0):

Blowfish is simple and common enough that you may be able to easily embed your own copy of the algorithm.